# Numeric Keypad On Devices For Password Field

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, input

I am aware that this has been asked many times, but none of the answers I have seen previously have worked for any devices that I am currently testing. None of the Android, iOS devices or Windows devices (Ranging from tablets to mobiles) implement the numeric keypad.

I am trying to implement a CV2 field on a website, and thus need the items to appear as a password field does. Below is the full input field with all I am currently using.

```
<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*" autocomplete="off" maxlength="3" class="fm-input--small" required spellcheck="false" name="cvvNumber" data-alt-name="the last 3 digits on the back of your card" placeholder="e.g. 412" id="cvvNumber" inputmode="numeric"/>
```

Despite all of these different ways, it doesn't come up with a numeric keypad. Tested on iOS 8.0.3 devices and Android 4.1.2 and 4.4.0 devices.

I have though about changing it to an type=number, and forcing it to be starred out. However, the only solution I have found is this:

```
-webkit-text-security: disc;
```

Which unfortunately I cannot use as I need it to be on the Windows devices. Previously as well, pattern=[0-9]* had worked a few months back but now doesn't. Does anyone know if support for this has been dropped?

I am also worried about

```
inputmode="numeric"
```

As it is not officially part of the HTML5 release yet. It doesn't work so I don't think it will be included.

I am happy to solve this through more than just CSS by the way. If a small amount of jQuery needs to be written that could be the best way. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This works on iPhone iOS 6.1.3. Weird...

Comment: Did you tried `numberPassword` in android?
`android:inputType="numberPassword"`

Comment: In android, you can give `numberPassword` to `inputType` tag of an `EditText`

Comment: it working in all devices

Answer (score 0):

In IOS, with help of below script you can open numeric keyboard.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

Or

```
<input type="number" />
```

and for Android.

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

[triggering-numeric-keyboards](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html)

Hope this help you.

Comment: As you can see I have these on the input box already. It doesn't bring up the numeric keyboard. Is there a syntax error on my input form that is not doing this?

Comment: @KirisuteRanza, actually i don't have code to check but i will give you direction that commenting your <input \> tag and replace it with just `<input type="number" />`. and check that weather you will get numeric keyboard.

Comment: I cannot do this <input type="number" /> as I need it to be like a password.

Comment: @KirisuteRanza, if you want to assign <input type="password" /> then it allowed to enter numbers as well as charecter. if you want restriction then you need to manage programmatically.

Comment: Yes... that is my question. How do I do that? 

Do I need to set it to password and some how force the numeric keypad to come up?

Or do I need to set it to tel/number and hide the characters through javascript or css?

Comment: Does not answer secret pin question.

Answer (score -2):

[image: This will help you make a number pad on ios]

1: Select your UITextfied
2: Go to Attribute Inspector 
3: Choose required "Keyboard type"

```
use  screenshot as a reference
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your screenshot. Just saying "this works..." is not really helpful. I will vote for your answer if you explain what you show.

Comment: I hope I've changed what you asked to change @JesperRønn-Jensen

Comment: I am not doing any app development. This is a website so it doesn't help me?